# Magento 2.3 example of where proxy is used but not explicitly requested in constructors

Tags: magento2.3, coding-standards

I'm trying to find an example in M2 repo where a proxy is used but not explicitly requested in a constructor.  Can anyone point me in the right direction?

This is in response to phpcs Magento2 ruleset error

```
Proxies and interceptors MUST never be explicitly requested in constructors.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's what an actual working example looks like

https://github.com/justbetter/magento2-sentry/blob/26daa9575a8e9f673aa6102558288ae46a436a60/Plugin/MonologPlugin.php

Before

```
    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function __construct(
        $name,
        Data\Proxy $data,
        SentryLog\Proxy $sentryLog,
        DeploymentConfig\Proxy $deploymentConfig,
        array $handlers = [],
        array $processors = []
    ) {
        $this->sentryHelper = $data;
        $this->sentryLog = $sentryLog;
        $this->deploymentConfig = $deploymentConfig;
        parent::__construct($name, $handlers, $processors);
    }
```

After

```
use JustBetter\Sentry\Model\SentryLog;
```

```
    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function __construct(
        $name,
        Data $data,
        SentryLog $sentryLog,
        DeploymentConfig $deploymentConfig,
        array $handlers = [],
        array $processors = []
    ) {
        $this->sentryHelper = $data;
        $this->sentryLog = $sentryLog;
        $this->deploymentConfig = $deploymentConfig;
        parent::__construct($name, $handlers, $processors);
    }
```

`etc/di.xml`

https://github.com/justbetter/magento2-sentry/blob/8d7adcce685ae1fba38187901dee894002d05c78/etc/di.xml#L14-L23

```
 <type name="JustBetter\Sentry\Plugin\MonologPlugin">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="name" xsi:type="string"></argument>
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="object">JustBetter\Sentry\Helper\Data\Proxy</argument>
            <argument name="sentryLog" xsi:type="object">JustBetter\Sentry\Model\SentryLog\Proxy</argument>
            <argument name="deploymentConfig" xsi:type="object">Magento\Framework\App\DeploymentConfig\Proxy</argument>
            <argument name="handlers" xsi:type="array"></argument>
            <argument name="processors" xsi:type="array"></argument>
        </arguments>
    </type>
```

Answer (score 1):

Proxies are injected via di.xml.

```
<type name="Your\Class">
    <arguments>
        <argument name="slowLoading" xsi:type="object">SlowLoading\Class\Proxy</argument>
    </arguments>
</type>
```

Mostly used them in console commands for now. Generally you can use them everywhere you want to delay the instantiation of a class with all its own dependencies until it is directly called upon.

[Magento DevDocs](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/extension-dev-guide/proxies.html)

Comment: Example in m2 git repo?

Comment: https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/2.3-develop/app/code/Magento/Catalog/etc/di.xml

Comment: Line number in xml? Corresponding classes with their usage?

Comment: I assume you're intelligent enough to perform a string search in a file/browser page for the word "Proxy". The corresponding class is given by the "name" attribute of the surrounding "type" tag. Example given in my answer.

Comment: So take this for example https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/dc2ad7c38cacb1cd4ea99beab98819e43a4a546e/app/code/Magento/Catalog/etc/di.xml#L112-L114 where is it used here https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/2.3-develop/app/code/Magento/Catalog/Helper/Product.php

Comment: You do not use a proxy directly. By defining it in the di.xml you simply tell Magento to use a proxy or might as well call it "dummy" for the dependency "$catalogSession" as long as it is not directly called. Upon the first call to or use of "$catalogSession" the autogenerated proxy will instantiated the real object. Proxies are just dummies that are used to reduce the number of dependencies loaded if not used in an instance. The helper in your example has functions that never call the session. So it does not need to be fully loaded.

Comment: So have you got an example where proxy is in XML and it is used in the class. I know what a proxy is. I just wanted an example. That's what I was after in the original question.

Comment: I gave you an example above. There is nothinc more to it. You define it in the di.xml, Magento auto generates the proxy, the class will use it instead of the original injected class. End of story. You wont find a written out Proxy class used in a actual class. So there can't be an example...

Comment: By used I mean within a method